Error Deploying Solana Nodes on OVH Machines: QUIC Connection Timed Out
I've been deploying 2 solana nodes (1 RPC and 1 Validator) on OVH machines, but I've encountered the following error:
2024-05-14T11:06:39.244108182Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled
[2024-05-14T11:06:39.405284735Z WARN  solana_core::validator] authorized voter: 944J56TN1kS13hWsCk7i4fcWMjGy2DSWxPghMUZACKbD
[2024-05-14T11:06:59.597116253Z WARN  solana_quic_client::nonblocking::quic_client] Failed to send data async to 10.20.30.167:8009, error: Custom("ConnectionError(TimedOut)") 
[2024-05-14T11:06:59.597251323Z WARN  solana_core::warm_quic_cache_service] Failed to warmup QUIC connection to the leader 944J56TN1kS13hWsCk7i4fcWMjGy2DSWxPghMUZACKbD, Error Custom("\"ConnectionError(TimedOut)\"")

All the ports used in the port range are open in both servers (validator and rpc) and the config in the RPC node is:
--snapshot-interval-slots 1000 
--full-rpc-api 
--allow-private-addr 
--no-incremental-snapshots 
--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader 
--tpu-use-quic 
--tpu-enable-udp 
--rpc-port 8899 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 
--identity /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/identity.json 
--accounts /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/ledger/accounts 
--ledger /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/ledger 
--log /opt/logs/solana-validator.log 
--limit-ledger-size 50000000 
--vote-account /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/vote-account.json 
--gossip-host 10.20.30.166 
--gossip-port 8001

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Best regards

If your nodes are unstaked or have low stake, they will not be allocated many QUIC connections by the rest of the cluster, which will mean timeouts when trying to connect to other nodes.
You can either get more stake delegated to your nodes or use some configuration of stake-weighted quality of service with other nodes to give your nodes more connections.

Thank you for your suggestion regarding increasing the stake. However, I have already ensured a significant amount of stake for my node (approximately 50000 SOL), as indicated below:

Average Stake-Weighted Skip Rate: 0.00%;
Average Unweighted Skip Rate:     0.00%;
Active Stake: 49999.998032004 SOL;
Stake By Version: 1.17.27 -    1 current validators (100.00%);

I still have the same error

I forgot to mention that I'm working with a private cluster. In a private cluster, I have control over the total supply within the network, so validator stake wasn't the problem.
The root cause was actually the kernel version on my machine. I updated the kernel to the latest version, and now I can successfully send transactions via QUIC.
Best regards

At present, the total number of pledges in the network has reached 365m, and 50000sol accounts for about 0.013% of the share. The total number of connections allocated to validators is 2000, so the connection allocated to your validator is approximately 2000✘0.013%=0.27 connection. So I think that might be the reason. Nice to keep talking to you
